# Moving the login button to the right side via bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a new user here and a beginner in the web programming area of life.

I've just started to create my own site with bootsrap and can't move the signin button with a link to the signin site above the navbar with the order btn-pull-right. How can I move the signin button to the right side of screenplay so that the link to the login site does functioning as well? Here is my code:

```
<body>         
    <div class="container" id="topContent">             
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-pull-right" href="../probe/signin.html" role="button">Sign in</a>         
    </div>         
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar">             
    <div class="container-fluid">                 
    <div class="navbar-header">
```

Comment: It should be "pull-right" and not "btn-pull-right"

Comment: That's the solution! Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css :

create a class (signinbtn for exemple) and put it on position: absolute. As so :

```
.signinbtn {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right 10px;
}
```

then add your class to the btn : as so :

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-pull-right signinbtn" href="../probe/signin.html" role="button">Sign in</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to solve this problem, but it does not functioning well, because your code pulls the whole site together and I don' want it to look like that. I want to use the whole widht of the site.

Comment: Adam, if you want to use the whole width of the site using bootstrap, you must use a container-fluid and the column system (col-xs, col-lg, etc.) Putting an absolute div does not pulls the whole page together if it do so it's because you did something wrong. You must give us the css and the whole page html code. And read the bootstrap doc

Comment: I see, this might be more reasonable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `btn-pull-right` should be just `pull-right`, as you can see from [Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)

Comment: Thank you, the problem is already solved by deleting the "btn" segment before "pull-right".

Comment: @Adam.Biczo yes exactly. I don't know if you knew how this site works, but once you choose an answer that fits your question and is the solution, you press the tick and mark it as the correct answer.